# Is There a CMS That Only Manages Content? Not Layout/CSS/SEO

Tags: php, css, content-management-system

I currently have a website that has the layout, CSS, and SEO covered. I need a much more improved way of managing content/articles. Most CMS I have come across require you to build the site around their specific syntax for CSS/php.

All I need is a very simple CMS that can be easily integrated into a site already complete.

Does anyone have any knowledge of something simple? XML/php based but very light?

```
<site code>
<article title>
<article author>
<site code>
<article content>
<site code>
```

Would be the basic implementation required. article title, author, and content would need to pull from where the info is stored, while not interfering with the structure of the site.

Does any such CMS exist?

If not, does anyone have a link to a specific guide on php/xml/mysql that could solve this issue if I built something on my own?

Comment: I've used CMS Made Simple in the past and i've found it easier than some other solutions for what you are talking about. We would mockup all the page variations in static html, then create page templates in the cms based off this. Then it's just a matter of replacing the static chunks of content with their tags like {{content}} etc. This, in my opinion is much easier than fiddling with an existing theme.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at this article on [Flexible CMSs](http://www.queness.com/post/14579/6-lightweight-flexible-php-cms) and checking out each of the solutions until you find one that matches your needs. The majority of them are free, too.

If you are knowledgeable enough in PHP, you could write your own CMS and then you'd have complete control. Even the lightest of systems will have extra features that you won't use, so you could really tailor the system to project's needs. If you go down this route then I think [this article](http://baylorrae.com/the-basics-of-creating-a-cms-with-php/) will get you started nicely, but a quick Google search for "Basic CMS PHP" will yield loads of great articles.

I also wouldn't completely rule out using Wordpress as your CMS. Sure you'll need to implement the design you already have and that might take a while but no more so really than creating a basic CMS of your own. Wordpress is extremely powerful and you'd be hard pushed to match its standard of SEO, not to mention all the time saving plugins, role-based permissions, content editor and easy of use.

Comment: I will take a look at the CMS's you linked. However, I am leaning towards the article you posted on making a basic CMS of some sort. That may prove to be what I'm looking for. "Inline CMS" sounds like what I need.

Comment: Great! If you opt for Inline CMS, if you could mark my answer as correct that'd really help me out. Let me know if you need any further help.